# my jQuery alert() its not showing

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im starting to study jQuery and ajax, and Im doing my first test but it isnt working.

Im saying that on click on my class="test" I want to alert 'CLICK'.

But it is not working, do you see what Im doing wrong?

This is my jQuery:

```
   var read = $('.news');
    read.on('click','.test',function(){
        alert('CLICK');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only be using one class attribute:

```
echo '<p>'.$readNewsResult['content'].'<a class="test fancybox" href="#fancybox' . $readNewsResult['id_news'].'">Read More</a></p>';
```

And try wrapping your jQuery in a ready handler:

```
$(function(){
   var read = $('.news');
   read.on('click','.test',function(){
       alert('CLICK');
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advise Adrift. But even with this change, its not showing!

Comment: @OzzC: See the update. Also do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I tried with ready handler, and with your code but its not working. And I dont have any error on console!

Comment: Its strange, I have a scripts.js file where I have some jQuery scripts. And I was doing there and dint work, even with your help and code. But now I move this script to header of my php file and it worked!